# How to create a condition when I have all element on array with same status

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a condition which executes the function only when all elements in the array are with status 3, if the array has an element with status 3 or different from 3 I should not execute the function.

I tried this code but doesn't work when I have element with status  3 ore different status.

```
   goToPeople(): void {
    const selectedItems = this.ms.selectedItems;
      selectedItems.forEach(item => {
        if (item.status !== 3){
          console.log('nonnnnnn');
        }else{
          console.log('yesss');
          //my function
        }
      });
  }
```

This is JSON:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2021-10-14T16:48:05+00:00",
        "status": 3,
        "name": "HRDD",
        "id": "ab8d4bd7"
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-10-14T16:55:05+00:00",
        "status": 2,
        "name": "ddfgdfgd",
        "id": "adfgdfgdf45"
    }
]
```

Comment: instead of each use filter, then compare length of filtered to original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the array `every` function is used for this purpose, it returns `true` if every element in the array matches the condition, otherwise `false`, so:

```
if (selectedItems.every(item => item.status === 3)) {
   // execute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the *best* way to do it, but this is how I usually handle situations like this (forgive syntax errors, I've only written JS not TS):

```
let execute = true;
selectedItems.foreach(item => {
    if(item.status !== 3){
        execute = false;
    }
});
if(execute) console.log('yes');
else console.log('nonnnnnn');
```

Basically just keep a bool that toggles off if any element fails to meet your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce should get you what you want...

```
const execute = selectedItems.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (acc === false) return;
    return item.status === 3;
}, true);
```

This will go through each item in the array. If they are ALL 3, it will return true. If any are not, it will return false. Edge case, if the array is empty, it will return true. So you need to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fucntion like this:

```
statusValid(selectedItems): boolean {
   var valid = true
   selectedItems.forEach(item => {
      if (item.status !== 3){
         valid = false;
      } 
   });
   return valid;
}
```

and then:

```
    goToPeople(): void {
        const selectedItems = this.ms.selectedItems;
        if(statusValid(selectedItems )){
            // your function here
    
        }
   }
```

Comment: The return true inside of the forEach will not return from the outer function. Only return from the inner foreach iteration.

Comment: Fixed, thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
goToPeople(): void {
    const selectedItemsFIlterd = this.ms.selectedItems.filter(selected => selected.status === 3);
    selectedItemsFiltered.forEach(item => {
      this.yourFunction();
    });
}
```

I hope this help you, regards.